# Javascript Validation database

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

I have a Javascript code (below) which validates mobile numbers. It's working fine. But the problem I am facing is both valid and invalid mobile numbers are being inserted into the database. I want only valid mobile numbers to be inserted into the database.

The code is as follows. Can anyone suggest any ideas to change the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CheckINumber(INumber) {
    var INum = /^[+]{1}[0-9]{2}-\d{10}$/;
    if(INum.test(INumber)) {
      alert("Your Mobile Number Is Valid.");
    } else {
      alert("Your Mobile Number Is Not Valid.");
    }
  }
  <input name="Upload" type="submit" height="25" class="uploadbutton" onClick="CheckINumber(mobile.value);"
```

Comment: return False after "Invalid alert". i.e. before closing brace of else in this case.

Comment: otherwise, by default it executes further code, considering that every entered number is valid.

Comment: You need to validate in the server-side too, because the user can disable javascript and bypass your client-side validation.

Comment: Hi sujith thanks for your suggestion I tried but then also it is being inserted into database...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a form? If so you should do:

```
<form method="post" name="form_name" action="your_submit_url" onsubmit="return(CheckINumber(mobile.value));">
```

Also:

```
function CheckINumber(INumber)
{
  var INum = /^[+]{1}[0-9]{2}-\d{10}$/; 

  if(INum.test(INumber)) { return true; }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert `false` in the invalid case to signal it failed to prevent the script from continuing.

```
if(INum.test(INumber))
{
 alert("Your Mobile Number Is Valid.");  
} 
else
{
  alert("Your Mobile Number Is Not Valid.");  
  return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. But an explanation to go with the answer will make it useful to everyone viewing the post and not just the OP.